# Ethereum net node crawler

Tags: go-ethereum

I would like to crawl an Ethereum-like network completely and find out the list of their node IP addresses and clients they have, in a format like this:

```
Geth/v1.7.2-stable/linux-amd64/go1.8.3    10.24.173.89
Geth/v1.7.2-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2   189.34.1.168
```

Something similar that happens in web, when a web crawler crawls the web and collects all the information about pages. Does something like this exist for Ethereum? I mean, some software I could download and run?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but probably of use (incl. some issues with crawling): https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/198/how-many-nodes-are-there-on-the-ethereum-network (and, if you look at the testnet stats, I'm sure you'll see how off the practical numbers are)

Comment: @lungj thanks a lot! these links would help to develop the code in javascript