# How many nodes are supporting Ethereum Classic?

Tags: nodes, ethereum-classic, network, statistics

To avoid high fees, I am considering deployment of Smart Contracts on Ethereum Classic (around 20 fold cheaper than ETH) but a concern is about network soundness and security. So I was wondering how many nodes are operating rigth now the ETC network.

This page:

```
http://etcstats.net/
```

says there are only 10 nodes but it also says that it does not represent the entire state of the ethereum classic network.

The equivalent https://ethstats.net/ seems not very reliable about the number of active nodes, declaring 50 of them, while other sources claim ETH has 6,000 or even 20,000.

Any idea how much is this number on a real basis? Or how to find out? Thx!

Refs.:

[How many ETH vs ETC full nodes are there?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7677/how-many-eth-vs-etc-full-nodes-are-there)

[How many nodes are there on the Ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/198/how-many-nodes-are-there-on-the-ethereum-network)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should think about hashrate, not about number of running nodes. As for now Ethereum Сlassic network hashrate is about 8.9TH/s, and Ethereum hashrate is 107.5TH/s. So Ehtereum Classic network "power" is 8.2% of Ethereum network. I do not know it safe or not, possible it can help you to estimate.

Links:

http://etcstats.net/ For Ethereum classic

https://ethstats.net/ For Ethereum

Answer (score 0):

You may wanto to check (seems for ETH only):

https://www.ethernodes.org/network/1